# USB PTP Camera not showing in Virtualbox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, camera, ptp

Running 20.04.2. I have a Fujifilm X-S10 camera and it shows up fine as USB PTP camera when connected. I want to passthrough the connection to Virtualbox running Windows 10. When trying to add a USB filter in Virtualbox I get the message that no devices are connected. I tried to add manually the device by adding the Vendor ID and Product ID but to no avail.

Any idea why and how I could resolve this?

```
lsusb | grep Fuji
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 04cb:02ea Fuji Photo Film Co., Ltd USB PTP Camera
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

My bad, added the user to vboxusers group and problem solved.